# Open an at runtime decrypted file with a third party application without storing the decrypted data

Tags: android, security, android-intent, android-contentprovider

In my application I need to pass a dynamically decrypted file to a third-party application without saving it to the device.

Example: I have a self created encrypted file which contains both a pdf file and some requirements before the pdf file can be shown. If all requirements are true, that pdf file should be shown by a third-party PDF-reader.

So I need to start a new intent, but there is the problem. I have to give the URI of my pdf file, but I don't have a URI because I didn't save the file to the device.

Is there any way I can get this job done?

Comment: Does the third-party PDF reader have support for showing files already in RAM or do you need to emulate an actual file?

Comment: I need to emulate an actual file. I have no way of knowing what PDF reader the user will use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer on my own question:

Together with the answer from CommensWare (and [sample code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe)) and [this link](http://blog.tomgibara.com/post/779006479/sharing-dynamic-resources) I have found a semi-solution.

The sample code shows you how to make local files accessible for other applications with a content provider.
The second link describes the implementation of a delete method which deletes the file from the file structure even before it is completely opened by a third party application (and explains why this is possible).

So basically, after decryption,  you create a file accessible from the content provider, open it with another application and delete it immediately.

For rooted phones this is still not a 100% solution because they could monitor local file structure changes and instantly copy the file after it has been created.

Answer (score 3):

For very small PDFs, or PDFs encrypted with some sort of streaming encryption algorithm, you can create a pipe `ContentProvider`. Using a pipe, you basically pour data into an `OutputStream`, where the other side uses a `Uri` and `ContentResolver` to retrieve the corresponding `InputStream`.

However, the limits of heap space will severely constrain the size of the file, if you cannot process it in a streaming fashion (e.g., as you read the bytes in from HTTP, decrypt on the fly and pass the decrypted bytes to the `OutputStream`).

[Here is a sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe) of creating such a `ContentProvder`.

Comment: But in your example you still use a file located in your assets folder. Is there an example with a dynamic generated file?

Comment: @robokop: "But in your example you still use a file located in your assets folder" -- correct. "Is there an example with a dynamic generated file?" -- probably not. The difference is just in terms of what you pour into the `OutputStream`. That is rudimentary Java I/O.